# 'Invalid Mounth' when Importing excel with date time into Oracle DB using SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to import data from excel files, using data import wizard, but i get issues with date type. My dates type in excel is 'DD/MM/YYYY'

I tried various solutions found on other threads but none of them worked for me:

I tried changing the datestamp in NLS (tools -> preferences -> NLS) from DD/MM/RR to MM/DD/RR, DD/MM/RRRR or DD/MM/YYYY, but i got fails in the check window.

I also tried to change dates format in my excel into 'MM/DD/YYYY'(without changing the NLS) it seemed to work, when i check i got all successfull until i clic end then i got errors: 'Invalid mounth for the line 1' and so on.

I have Sql devloper 3.2.20.10, dates type in my database is DATE.

Comment: I noticed that even if i change the date format in excel, it doesnt change in the preview window of Data import wizard...

Comment: if you want exemples of the data: '02/01/2019', '05/01/2019', '07/01/2019', ...

Comment: What issues do you get, exactly? When you get to the 'column definition' step, are you entering the format for the target table column?

Comment: 3.2 is so old but in the wizard is a page where you define a date mask that describes the data coming from Excel...you need to do that ... Also, upgrade :)

Comment: The issue that i get is that the data won't go inside the database...

Comment: i tried it without toutching the format, and with differents formats 'DD/MM/YYYY' 'MM/DD/YYYY' it doesnt work

Comment: I'm downloading the latest version now

Answer (score 0):

I updated my sql developer to the latest version and now it works just fine.

I guess the data import wizard in older versions wasn't that good.